# How to improve the accuracy when using computer calculating?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, computer-science

In practical application, it is often required to calculate a certain sum of the series (accurate to a certain decimal place) and there is no doubt that I will use a computer to calculate that
For example,Basel problem，we know that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
If Calculate the sum of the first n terms.

The actual result should be to add up the denominators and then convert them to decimals

$1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{16}+···+\frac{1}{n^2}$
,we first caculate the Least Common Multiple of {$1、4、9、···、{n^2}$},then add up to get a fraction, then convert it to a decimal（Can also be accumulated item by item）

Howerever，Computers don't use fractions when calculating，Assuming that the computer can store 8 significant digits，the Actual calculation is
$1+0.25+0.1111111+0.625+0.04+0.0277778+···$
Whether Float or Double，In fact, each individual term has errors.The final result is definitely has error.

Consider the general situation,Will this error be offset or will it accumulate？

So how to improve the accuracy when using computer calculating?

Comment: In general computers have algorithms to evaluate things that are different to the math we are used to.

Comment: @Gabrielek：You mean The total error will not increase with the increase of calculation times？